# Fixed IP address for Kubernetes worker node managed by AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, kubernetes, amazon-vpc

I'm using a managed [AWS EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/de/eks/) Kubernetes cluster. For the worker nodes I have setup a node group within the EKS cluster with 2 worker nodes

[image: Node Group]

These worker nodes get a public IP assigned automatically by EKS:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                                          STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION              INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP     OS-IMAGE         KERNEL-VERSION                  CONTAINER-RUNTIME
ip-10-0-0-129.eu-central-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   6d    v1.14.7-eks-1861c5   10.0.0.129    1.2.3.4         Amazon Linux 2   4.14.146-119.123.amzn2.x86_64   docker://18.6.1
ip-10-0-1-218.eu-central-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   6d    v1.14.7-eks-1861c5   10.0.1.218    5.6.7.8         Amazon Linux 2   4.14.146-119.123.amzn2.x86_64   docker://18.6.1
```

For this example let's assume that the values assigned automatically by AWS are `1.2.3.4` and `5.6.7.8`.

When running a command from inside a pod running on the first node I can also see that this is the IP address with which external requests are being made:

```
$ curl 'https://api.ipify.org'
1.2.3.4
```

The issue that I'm facing now is that I would like to configure this IP address. Let's assume I have a service that I use from within the pod that I'm not in control of and that requires whitelisting via IP address.

I haven't found any way to specify a range of IP addresses to the node group (or the subnets setup for the VPC in which the cluster is located) from which AWS will pick an IP address.

Is there any other way to configure the worker nodes to use fixed IP addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to associate Elastic IPs with instances running as part of EKS node group. However, I will provide you with a much better alternative that should be used over your setup which is essentially all public.

Firstly, run your worker nodes or node groups inside private subnets. This will give you the ability to route out to internet through a static ip.

To achieve static ip that you can whitelist on a desired service is by using NAT Gateway. [Setup instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/). NAT gateway will be associated with an elastic IP which won't be changing.

Since you are running EKS, don't forget to modify aws-vpc-cni configuration with `AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_EXTERNALSNAT = true`. This is essential for pods to correctly work and route out to internet. If set to true, the SNAT iptables rule and off-VPC IP rule are not applied, and these rules are removed if they have already been applied. For this your nodes must be running in a private subnet and connected to the internet through an AWS NAT Gateway or another external NAT device. [more info on aws-vpc-cni](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s)